# Creating a UIView with background in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I'm creating a UIView on a controller purely by code (I'm not using storyboards at all.

here's the code for that simple view:

```
let greenView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 183, green: 202, blue: 45)
    v.layer.borderWidth = 1
    return v
}()
```

When I setup the views in the screen I have:

```
    view.addSubview(greenView)
    greenView.anchor(top: joined.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: 200)
```

This "anchor" function is just an extension to help setting up the auto layout constrains and it works well including all other components like UIButton that actually inherits from UIView.

The problem: the view does not show up on screen in any position... am I missing something?

For the anchor method I'm using [LBTAComponents](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents).

More specifically [this class](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents/blob/master/LBTAComponents/Classes/UIView%2BAnchors.swift)
Worked fine so far with all other methods.

Comment: The behavior suggests the constraints aren't working. Why not show this extension you are using? Better yet, don't use the extension - simply add the "long" code to this view and see if it works. If so, then work "backwards" to the extension.

Comment: Have you looked for the view in the [view debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2)? Be sure to turn off clipping in the debugger so you can see the view even if it's clipped.

Comment: @robmayoff it does show up on stack but it says that height is ambiguous.

Comment: @dfd I am defining the size in the constrains last 2 parameters in the anchor method.

extension is [LBTAComponets](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents)

Comment: I tried this code, but using my own auto layout constrains, it is working fine. Your extension of anchor has problem......Please double check your extension code......

Comment: If it says the height is ambiguous, then I suspect there is a bug in your `anchor` method. You should editor your question to include the entire source code of the `anchor` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're using [LBTAComponents](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents), but your method signatures don't match. They're close, but look like they're using some old version (tho looking at the history, I don't see an old version that matches the method signatures you're employing above) or you have your own extensions wrapping this API. For example, the following code:

```
greenView.anchor(top: joined.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 20, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: 200)
```

should be:

```
greenView.anchor(joined.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 20, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: view.bounds.width - 20, heightConstant: 200)
```

When I corrected the method signatures and used it with the latest version of LBTAComponents, the code works fine. So the problem must rest in the version of those extensions (or whatever layer you're using to wrap that library to yield the API above).

Comment: Thanks it is true, I followed some tutorials on youtube from the author of this LBTAComponents and I had an old extension with that anchor method... Silly me.. Thanks a lot @Rob.